# $\lambda$ an eigenvalue then $T-\lambda$ not surjective

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm stuck in this question and I'm wondering if this is true for a linear transformation $T:V\to V$ with $V$ an arbitrary vector space (not necessarily with finite dimention)

Comment: @Randall $T-\lambda$ is a TL definited like $(T-\lambda)x=Tx-\lambda Ix$ where I is the identity

Comment: It is not true for infinite-dimensional spaces.

Comment: let $V$ be a vector space with basis $\{b_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$, and let $T$ be the unique linear map $V\to V$ which sends $b_1$ to zero and sends $b_{n+1}$ to $b_n$ for all $n>1$. then $0$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ but $T-0=T$ is surjective

Comment: If $dim(V)<+\infty$ it is true. If $dim(V)=\infty$ in general it is not true and it brings the definition of spcetrum and point spectrum, which in finite dimension are the same thing. Of course there are some classes of operators(e.g. compact operators) which satisfy this property like in the finite dimensional case

Comment: Another example is the space of infinitely-differentiable function on $\mathbb R.$ Then the linear function $f\mapsto \frac{df}{dx}$ is onto, but sends the constant functions to $0.$